# Angular 2 RC6 - Setting default params in URL and redirect to route with params

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have done a lot a research but I don't seem to find the exact answer...

My problem is simple; I have a route, let's call it "parent/child", and I want to set default params in it if the params are not provided (parent/child?param1=xxx&param2=xxx and so on).

I constantly need params in my URL because it allows me to update some graphs on my page that rely on these params. I also want them in the URL and not on a localeStorage/Session or service because my users are susceptible to copy/paste to share the page.

I have tried several things, like:

```
{
        path: 'parent',
        component: Parent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'child',
                redirectTo: 'child:param1:param2'
            },
            {
                path: 'child:param1:param2',
                component: Child
            },
```

But it does not work. I have thought about a shared service between my components to set these params when they are not provided, but after that I guess I should do something like route.navigate([myLocation], myParams) to change the URL with the params.
So it means that each time I need to retrieve my current location ?

If someone could help me, I am a bit confused. Thanks !

EDIT : my app.routes :

```
{
        path: 'parent',
        component: Parent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'child',
                component: Child
            },
        ]
},
{
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '/parent/child'
}
```

Sorry if it is a silly question, it must be a syntax error...

Comment: What's the problem with the routes posted below "Edit"?

Comment: With a random URL, my URL doesn't stay with /parent/child, it does appear for a short amount of time, but I am being redirect to the root of my app

Comment: I guess this would require a Plunker to reproduce. I have no idea why it would behave this way.

Comment: It may be because of some other config. I'll try to dig that and come back to you. Thank you

Comment: Nevermind, it was my fault ! Thank you for your quick answers.

Answer (score 3):

Just add the URL like:

```ts
{
    path: 'child',
    redirectTo: 'child/a/b'
},
```

where `"a"` is the value for `param1` and `"b"` for `param2`

Comment: Wouldn't this attempt to navigate to subroute `/a/b` relative to `/child`? I didn't know this syntax could pass parameters to a route.  I thought it would be `child/:a/:b` if the parameters are required, or just `child` if they are optional

Comment: You need the `:` to define route parameters, not to pass actual values when navigating. I guess you are right about the redirect. I only paid attention to passing the parameters, not if the redirect example makes sense.

Comment: Oh yeah of course; `redirectTo` doesn't define a path. Brain freeze. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. So I have tried to navigate after setting my params, but now I am stumbling over redirecting routes.I have simply tried to give any random URL, in order to be redirected to /parent/child, but I am automatically redirected to the root. In the URL, after being shortly redirected to /parent/child, I am in the root of my app. I have something like this : `{
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '/parent/child'
    }`

Comment: Can you please create a new question or update above question with more details what you tried and what doesn't work as expected?

Answer (score 2):

As per the official router guide, routes can have required and optional query parameters.

Required parameters (ie /parent/child/required)

```
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/parent/child/required',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'parent',
    component: ParentComponent,
    children:[
      {
        path: 'child/:info',
        component: ChildComponent
      }
    ]
  }
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/35oXBWL1rg7biLgww3TF (click 'launch the preview in a separate window' to see the url)

Optional parameters (ie /parent/child?info=optional)

```
this.router.navigate(['/parent/child',{info: "optional"}]);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/HPwcfN9BUYqcSrWEawd6 (click 'launch the preview in a separate window' to see the url)

**edit: versions in systemjs hardcoded to fix plunkrs**

Comment: Seems you are mixing query and route parameters. Route parameters are defined in the `path` with `:` and query parameters are optional and added to the end of URL as query parameters (after `?` for the root route, or matrix parameters after `;` for child routes). The question seems to be about route parameters.

Comment: Hi Gunter. Yep, I agree 'required' route parameters are defined in the path and is probably what XTN needs as the question mentioned required populated parameters.  I only suggested the optional param method if XTN has a requirement to conform to the path[;?]param1=val1&param2=val2 url format... but, perhaps the redirect via router.navigate when a param isn't passed isn't 'good' practice?

Answer (score 1):

Routes only define required parameters. Do not include parameters that may or may not be present

```
{
    path: 'child',
    component: Child
}
```

To navigate to `Child` and provide several parameters you would do

```
this.router.navigate(['/parent/child', {optionA:value1,optionB:value2}]);
```

This will navigate to */parent/child;optionA=value1;optionB=value2*.  Inside the `Child` component, you subscribe to `ActivatedRoute.params` to be notified every time the parameters change.

**Child**

```
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
...
constructor(private activeRoute:ActivatedRoute, private router:Router){}

//chart options
optionA;
optionB;

//redraws the chart
redrawChart(){/*todo*/}

ngOnInit(){
    this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(
        //executed each time new params arrive
        params => {
            this.optionA = params['optionA'] || null;
            this.optionB = params['optionB'] || null;
            this.redrawChart();
        }
    );
}
```

To change the chart option, you could do

```
changeChart(a, b){
    this.router.navigate(['/parent/child',{optionA:a,optionB:b}]);
}
```

For more info on how to handle changing route parameters, [see the manual](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)  (search for *params.subscribe*)

With all that said, you are right. A `ChartService` would be much cleaner.  Your component could subscribe to a `chartOptionsChanged` Observable exposed by that service and just update the chart.